# Помогите переделать setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть такая команда в боте помогите её переделать чтобы прибавлялось по 1-ной энергии в течении 10 минут, то есть должно получиться также 5 энергии, но нужно чтобы она прибавлялась по одной в течении 10 минут.
(Сейчас прибавляется сразу 5 в 10 минут).

```
cmd.hear(/^(?:работать)$/i, async (message, bot) => {
    if(!message.user.work) return bot(`вы нигде не работаете 
    Для трудоустройства введите "Работа"`);

    if(message.user.energy -= 1) return bot(`рабочий день закончен.
    ⏳ Вы сможете работать в ближайшие 10 минут`);

    setTimeout(() => {
        message.user.energy = 5;
    }, 600000);

    const work = works.find(x=> x.id === message.user.work);
    const earn = utils.random(work.min, work.max);

    message.user.balance += earn;
    message.user.exp += 1;

    return bot(`рабочий день закончен 
     Вы заработали ${utils.sp(earn)}$`);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let myInterval = setInterval(() => {
    if(message.user.energy<5)
       ++message.user.energy;
    else clearInterval(myInterval);
}, 600000);
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.